# Finding timezone in HttpRequest from server side

Tags: c#, timezone, request-headers

I have tried `var dateHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Date"]` but it contains null, apparently there is no such key.

Can anyone tell me where else can I find the time-zone of the current client?

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

[image]

I want to parse dateTime to the following format:

> Sun Nov 14 43745 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)

btw, what's the '43745' part?

Comment: You could try finding the timezone by IP, definitely possible but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: If it actually is available then you'll get the date in UTC.  You already know that.  The holy grail for servers, exclusively working in UTC and only converting to local time at the endpoint is the only good solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The date header is not one that is sent in standard http requests. I just ran a quick check with fiddler using both IE and Firefox and didn't see the date header sent on any requests.

The best that you can do on the server is get the user's culture, but this will only help with the date format, not the timezone.

However, you can get the information from javascript using getTimezoneOffset. For example:

```
var timeNow = new Date();
var timezone = timeNow.getTimezoneOffset() / 60 * (-1);
```

There is an excellent description [here](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/).

Comment: does this honor day light savings?

Answer (score 0):

In client side add this to request header.

```js
request.headers["X-Timezone-Offset"] = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

In server side.

```js
import moment from "moment";

const userTimezoneOffset = Number(-req.headers['x-timezone-offset'])
const date = moment(ISODateString).utcOffset(userTimezoneOffset).format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a")

console.log(date)
```

By this you can convert the ISO date string to users time from server.

Comment: If the client is a web browser reacting to a mouse click, one cannot tell it what the request should look like.

Comment: Not getting you @LutzPrechelt, If the client is a web browser we already have the access to TimezoneOffset by web API (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) and we can send this Offset through the request header.

Comment: You are assuming the person asking the question is in control of the HTML page that generates the request. I think this assumption is not warranted. If the server offers a public API, then arbitrary clients may have sent the request. If the API has not required that header, one must not assume it will be present.

Comment: Do you agree that web browsers do not add such types of headers by default, or do you have a different understanding?

Comment: If the client's timezone offset is required by the server, the client should add it to the request header. Additionally, if it is a public API, the API documentation should contain information about the headers required by the server, including the X-Timezone-Offset header, if applicable. This would ensure that clients using the API are aware of the required headers and include them in their requests.