# how to get current time from server?

Tags: .net, datetime

I am trying to get Date & Time from server and it is returning me correct Date but time is not correct it is approx 12 Hour old time. 
for example if current Date & Time is **05-07-2016 02:47 PM** then from the server I received **05-07-2016 02:18 AM**. please any one give me correct solution.

I am working in MVC 4 And my code is given below.

```
public ActionResult getDT()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    string datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), "HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt");
    ViewBag.dt = datetime;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. What your timezone? What's your *server's* timezone?

Comment: And please don't break the title and tags. This has nothing at all to do with MVC. You ask for the current *local* time for your server, you get the current *local* time for your server. The clock may be wrong, but most likely the server is in a completely different timezone from your own

Comment: Sorry for wrong cultureInfo, recently i modified it please check again

Comment: The culture info only deals with formatting, not timezones. Assuming the server's clock isn't broken (which you can't fix), you need to convert the timezone from the server's to whatever you want. The best option is to use `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToOffset(someOffset)` instead of `DateTime.Now`

Comment: so how, I can get a correct clock from server.

Comment: can you provide me  any example.

Comment: You already have the correct clock. The problem is you want to *change* it to a different timezone. What timezone are you in? GB is at +1 righ now, which means the offset should be `new TimeSpan (1,0,0)`. If your timezone is different, you need a different timespan.

Comment: Instead of trying to format the time on the *server's* side, you should probably perform the formatting on the view with a format string or with Javascript. DateTimeOffset is serialized as an ISO8601 datetime *with* offset. And most MVC helpers contain a format string

Comment: A common trick to find the client's timezone in javascript is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690911/finding-timezone-in-httprequest-from-server-side)

Answer (score -1):

use this :   Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Date

Comment: `DateTime.Now` *is* a DateTime and the OP is asking about the *time* portion

Comment: DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now; // gives you current Time in server timeZone


TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");